# how do i control geom_errorbar width by symbol size?

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

In the below example i have a simple plot of mean values with standard deviation error bars for both X and Y axis. I would like to control the error bar width so both axis always plot the same size.

Ideally I would like the bar width/height to be the same size as the symbols (i.e. in this case cex = 3) irrelevant of the final plot dimensions. Is there a way to do this?

```
# Load required packages:
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

# Create dataset:
DF <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"),each=10),
  Ydata = c(seq(1,10,1),seq(5,50,5),seq(20,11,-1),seq(0.3,3,0.3)),
  Xdata = c(seq(1,10,1),seq(5,50,5),seq(20,11,-1),seq(0.3,3,0.3)))

# Summarise data:
subDF <- ddply(DF, .(group), summarise, 
                X = mean(Xdata), Y = mean(Ydata), 
                X_sd = sd(Xdata, na.rm = T), Y_sd = sd(Ydata))

# Plot data with error bars:
ggplot(subDF, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = X, 
                ymin = (Y-Y_sd), 
                ymax = (Y+Y_sd)), 
                width = 1, size = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(x = X, 
                    xmin = (X-X_sd), 
                    xmax = (X+X_sd)), 
                height = 1, size = 0.5) +
  geom_point(cex = 3)
```

Looks fine when plotted at  1:1 ratio (500x500):
[image: Plot1]

but the errorbar width/heigh look different when plotted at 600x200
[image: Plot2]

Answer (score 6):

I'd use a size-variable so you can control all of the 3 plot elements at the same time

```
geom_size <- 3

# Plot data with error bars:
ggplot(subDF, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = X, 
                    ymin = (Y-Y_sd), 
                    ymax = (Y+Y_sd)), 
                width = 1, size = geom_size) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(x = X, 
                     xmin = (X-X_sd), 
                     xmax = (X+X_sd)), 
                 height = 1, size = geom_size) +
  geom_point(cex = geom_size)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you misread my question. your answer does a good job controlling the 'size' (ie the line width). I'm looking to control the width/height of the bars.

Comment: Oh so you mean the length of the errorbars? and you want them to be the same length?

Comment: No the length of the error bars is the standard deviation and is defined by ymin and ymax.  I want to control the 'width' in geom_errorbar and the 'height in geom_errorbarh

Comment: ah now I've understood, you want the bar ends to be the same size as your datapoints

Answer (score 3):

This is just building on brettljausn earlier answer. You can control the ratio of your plot with a variable as well. This will only work when you actually save the file with `ggsave()` not in any preview. I also used `size` to control the size of the point. It scaled nicer with the error bar ends.

```
plotheight = 100
plotratio = 3
geomsize = 3 

plot = ggplot(subDF, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = X, 
                    ymin = (Y-Y_sd), 
                    ymax = (Y+Y_sd)), 
                width = .5 * geomsize / plotratio, size = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(x = X, 
                     xmin = (X-X_sd), 
                     xmax = (X+X_sd)), 
                 height = .5 * geomsize, size = 0.5) +
  geom_point(size = geomsize)  

ggsave(filename = "~/Desktop/plot.png", plot = plot, 
       width = plotheight * plotratio, height = plotheight, units = "mm")
```

Change the `plotheight`, `plotratio`, and `geomsize` to whatever you need it to be to look good. You will have to change the `filename` in the one but last line to get the file in the folder of your choice.

Comment: Thanks Stijn! your answer gets me half way there. seems to be the problem is 'width' is in somewhat real units, whereas cex is unitless and a scaling of default sizes. geom_errorbar doesnt allow access to the defaults it seems? I think i'll have to settle with trial and error method for now.